# How to continue execution when mobile device sleeps?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I'm developing an application that needs to execute until a count down. When the handled turns off the screen, the countdown halts. How can I continue the execution when this situation happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean that you want your code to continue executing after the device suspends?  First off, you can't.  When the device suspends, the processor stops running.  You have a couple options though.  You can periodically call [SystemIdleTimerReset](http://SystemIdleTimerReset) to prevent the device from suspending, run it in "[unattended mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/windowsmobile/archive/2004/11/29/271991.aspx)" so the backlight shuts off but the device does not suspend, or use an API like [CeRunAppAtTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa931253.aspx) to preiodically wake the processor to run your code.

Comment: Any clue to show the application when the countdown finishes?

Answer (score 1):

Note that there's an article on CodeProject.com that contains examples of managed (C#) code for using the Windows Mobile powermanagement features.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/WiMoPower1.aspx

Additionally information on starting an application due to various conditions from managed code can be found in a CodeProject.com article too.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/WiMoAutostart.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is another way - some "cheating method": **[Disable sleep mode in Windows Mobile 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246407/disable-sleep-mode-in-windows-mobile-6)**. It uses **SystemIdleTimerReset** and additionally simulates a key touch.