# How to make my Pocket PC stay on till my application has finished?

Tags: pocketpc

I've got an application that presents the user with ongoing status for roughly 15 minutes. What I want to do is make it so the unit will not power off during this time (because the wifi goes down and the status stops :( )

I'd assume the system is capable of doing this gracefully because I can watch a whole episode of Dilbert (22min) without having to touch my screen. At the same time, when the its over, the system goes to "sleep" (at least after a few min).

Keep alive if you please.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246407/disable-sleep-mode-in-windows-mobile-6

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to press a virtual "key" every so often:

keybd_event(VK_F24, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);

This will be ignored by applications and it will keep your device from timing out / suspending.

L.B.