# How to stop a PDA sleeping

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have an application for PDAs with a long running process, and I'm getting the problem that the PDA is going to sleep before the process has completed.

I haven't got any control over the power settings on the PDA, does anyone know a good way for my application to stop the PDA from going to sleep?

Many thanks

Comment: redbull?  Sorry, could not resist...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll.SystemIdleTimerReset

Comment: SystemIdleTimerReset seems like the way to get it working
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa930260.aspx

Answer (score 6):

You need to make a function that calls SystemIdleTimerReset, SHIdleTimerReset and simulates a key touch. Then you need to call it on a regular basis from within your application.

For an example in C++, look here:

[Disable sleep mode in Windows Mobile 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246407/disable-sleep-mode-in-windows-mobile-6)